# Is mxGraph library suitable for drawing complex electrical drawings like the one below?

Tags: javascript, drawing, mxgraph

I am evaluating mxGraph for drawing complex electrical diagrams like the ones below. If someone experienced with using mxGraph can provide their opinion it will help in choosing the right library.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion you could do something like this. I'm studing the library for a project like your